# Who will inherit these items?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, avengers-endgame

After the death of

> Tony Stark who will take his company?

Comment: I've removed the second post about the other character, if you want to know about them too ask another question else this will be too broad. Also please be mindful of spoilers for other users who may not have seen the film yet.

Answer (score 14):

The company is already run by Pepper Potts (Stark?) and it would almost certainly have been left to her and their daughter Morgan Stark in Tony's will if he had one.

Comment: He prepared a video in case of his untimely demise. So Stark may actually have a will.

Comment: @Shreedhar Yeah I was thinking about that but if he did we weren't shown it.

Comment: You're right... But we are ignoring the obvious here..Spider-Parker could also inherit Stark industries :P :P

Comment: Iirc Tony already gave Pepper the company or at least made CEO, or President or something. She has been effectively running the company for a while.